# Adding Volley Library AppController In Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-volley, android-manifest

I am using Volley library and want to add the AppController in manifest but i already have another application name. how can i use both of them

```
<application

    android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
        android:value="com.guidedkeys.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
        android:value="2" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_MODELS"
        android:value="com.guidedkeys.main.Video,com.guidedkeys.main.Category,com.guidedkeys.main.Favorites" />
```

Comment: share both  class with question with question

Comment: the other one isn't a class. as you can see..  android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application"

Comment: than what is the use of `com.activeandroid.app.Application` this than

Comment: I don't know,, the code is written by some one else. i tried to replace it with the AppController it give me error .... DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APK

Comment: share this class with question `com.activeandroid.app.Application`

Comment: If i would have known that than it was quite an easy task ... but there is no class com.activeandroid.app.Application

Comment: than remove it and add `AppController` class in manifest file

Comment: It is actually there for     compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: i did that but it generated error while installing apk